# vector tiling of point set

Tags: tiles, tilecache, vector-tiles

I have large point set which I want to overlay on open-Street map. That is to create vector tiles of the point set based on zoom levels of the underlying Open-Street map. For example if the current zoom level of open-Street map that I'm viewing is 5, I want to create vector tile of the point set for the same zoom level, and then overlay this. With this approach, I'm trying to cluster the points and serve as tiles.Is there some one who have used and succeeded implementing  this approach? or does this approach make sense?